# Couldn't hide mobile menu item in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, header, display

I have a specific mobile menu item in WordPress that needs to be hidden when specific conditions are met (ex: User coming from Singapore), which means the code includes **Javascript**.

However, the mobile menu item cannot be hidden without using window.onload (load after page refresh), which caused the hidden mobile menu item to appear briefly after each refresh.

The desktop menu item can be hidden just fine without window.onload, it is just the mobile menu item attribute in WordPress that cannot be altered.

```
window.onload = function() {
if (localStorage.country !== 'sg/'){
  jQuery(".sg-menu-item").hide();
}
}
```

Does anyone have any idea on this?

Comment: Why can't this be done with CSS?

Comment: Because there are javascript associated.